# Ignore unresolved reference in tensorflow.python

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm looking to make my tensorflow code fully reproducible, so next to setting a fixed seed everywhere, I want to call `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.reset_default_graph()`.

The current way I do this is by calling

```
from keras.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
```

but despite this working, my IDE (PyCharm) keeps flagging this as an unresolved reference.

Some digging in the code shows that `tensorflow.__init__()` explicitly deletes its reference to the `tensorflow.python` module after importing everything from it. This is also why directly calling `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.reset_default_graph()` doesn't work, that results in a warning that `tensorflow has no property 'python'`.

My question is therefore: how can I get rid of this warning? As in: how can I either import `ops` a better way to not trigger the warning, or tell PyCharm to simply ignore this particular unresolved reference warning (without disabling reference resolving completely) so that the red exclamation mark stops showing?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm facing the same issue.